# primefaces themes broken

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I'm trying to use a different theme on my primefaces (2.2.1) web application but I'm experiencing a strange behavior. Where I should get this (primefaces.org showcase) :

[image: img]http://dl.dropbox.com/u/7117743/primefacetheme_demo.png[/img]

I'm getting this :

[image]

I'm using the same code as the demo, minus the event handlers and theme roller. The demo can be found there : http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/layoutComplex.jsf the source code of the page is linked in the bottom.

I've tried another theme and I have a similar result.

What I did:

I've added

```
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="theme/primefaces-sunny/theme.css" />
```

in the head section

I've added

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>primefaces.skin</param-name>
    <param-value>none</param-value>
</context-param>
```

to the web.xml file

I have no knowledge of css, I really don't know what could have gone wrong. Any help is appreciated, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to remove link tag and set theme name as the context param value. More info;

http://www.primefaces.org/themes.html

Comment: Thanks it did it, it seems I've been following the installation steps of an older version.