# PrimeFaces 2.2.1 looks different locally than in showcase

Tags: css, jsf, primefaces

I've seen similar questions asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5226837/primefaces-themes-broken) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4583397/primefaces-style-doenst-work-correctly).  Neither of these answered my question.  I've also searched the [PrimeFaces forum](http://forum.primefaces.org/).

Setting up a vanilla JSF 2.0 project in NetBeans, I've added the Showcase code for [Simple Dialog](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/dialog.jsf).

**Code (index.xhtml) minus the xml declaration and DOCTYPE (XHTML 1.0 Transitional):**

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
  xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
  xmlns:p="http://primefaces.prime.com.tr/ui">
<h:head>
    <title>PrimeFaces</title>
</h:head>
<h:body>
    <h:panelGrid columns="1" cellpadding="5">
        <p:commandButton value="Basic" onclick="dlg1.show();" type="button"/>

        <p:commandButton value="Modal" onclick="dlg2.show();" type="button"/>

        <p:commandButton value="Effects" onclick="dlg3.show();" type="button"/>
    </h:panelGrid>

    <p:dialog header="Basic Dialog" widgetVar="dlg1">
        <h:outputText value="Resistance to PrimeFaces is futile!" />
    </p:dialog> 

    <p:dialog header="Modal Dialog" widgetVar="dlg2" modal="true" height="200">
        <h:outputText value="This is a Modal Dialog." />
    </p:dialog> 

    <p:dialog header="Effect Dialog" widgetVar="dlg3" showEffect="bounce" hideEffect="explode" height="200">
        <h:outputText value="This dialog has cool effects." />
    </p:dialog>
</h:body>
```

I've added the `aristo` theme to my `Libraries` (NetBeans way of adding to the classpath) and added the following to `web.xml`

**web.xml (partial):**

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>primefaces.THEME</param-name>
    <param-value>aristo</param-value>
</context-param>
```

No other changes were made, although I quickly installed/uninstalled another theme (dark-hive) just to make certain that the theme was being registered properly.  The results are as follows:

**Local (Chrome 15.0.874.92):**

[image: Screenshot of locally created site]

**Showcase: (from [PrimeFaces Showcase](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/dialog.jsf))**

[image]

**Stack:**
PrimeFaces 2.2.1
JSF 2.0
Glassfish 3.1.1
Java 1.6.0_18
Windows 7 x64
(Generated by NetBeans 7.0.1)

**Edit:** This was also tested on FireFox 7.0.1 and IE 9

Comment: Can you provide more details about "I've added the aristo theme to my Libraries".  Did you add the jar to your project's Libraries or did you create a library?  If you build your project and explore into the war file (in the Files explorer) do you see what you expect?

Comment: @vkraemer I added the jar from my Libraries which is included with the JSF/PrimeFaces plugin.  This is located at `<NB_INSTALL>/enterprise/modules/ext/primefaces/primefaces-2.2.1.jar`.  Yes, I see what I expect from the directory that is deployed (NetBeans does an inplace-deploy).  This is a good point though and I will download the library from PrimeFaces.org and see if there's a change.

Comment: @vkraemer After switching to the downloaded jar I see no change.

Comment: I also deployed it to the server (as opposed to inplace).  No change

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Isn't the problem the default font sizes? I can see from the [showcase css](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/css/default.css) that it has custom font sizes overriding the theme's default:

```
body {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0;
    font-size: 12px;
    color: #616161;
}
```

I checked some of my projects and all of them also have some font-size/font-family customization. Hope it helps

Answer (score 5):

I read your 3 posts. What's you problem here? Can you describe you problem more specifically? I mean, how different are they?

If it about font size, check [PrimeFaces' Document](http://www.primefaces.org/documentation.html). **At Chapter 8.4: Themeing Tips: (Chapter 7.4 in User Guide 3.4 and later)**

*Default font size of themes might be bigger than expected, to change the font-size of PrimeFaces
components globally, use the .ui-widget style class. An example of smaller fonts;*

```
.ui-widget, .ui-widget .ui-widget {
     font-size: 90% !important;
}
```

Hope that it can help u :)